# Why does Umbraco treat IPublishedContent differently when called via AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

The short story is I have a list of blog articles which I'm casting to a model which contains .wordCount. This is calculated by striping the HTML from the output of the RTE and then calculating the lengh. The output of the RTE can contain Macros.

On first load, i.e from a view, the output of the RTE renders my Macros as HTML. However, when I refresh my list articles using a clientside AJAX the output of the RTE is rendered differently. My Macros now look like this: `<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="ArticleAudio" audioPicker="6068" audioPosition="left" audioTitle="Interview Audio" />`

I also get the error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot render a macro when there is no current PublishedContentRequest.`

```
public static Article ToArticle(this IPublishedContent item)
{
    string rawText = HelperFunctions.StripHTML(item.GetPropertyValue<string>("richText"));
    ...
}

public static string StripHTML(string htmlString)
{
    string pattern = @"<(.|\n)*?>";
    return Regex.Replace(htmlString, pattern, string.Empty);
}
```

**Expected**

```
<div class="audio-player">
    <audio style="display: none;">
        <source src="https://www.address.com/media/77390/interview.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>
```

**My Output**

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="ArticleAudio" audioPicker="6068" audioPosition="left" audioTitle="Interview Audio" />
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What is the url that you are calling with AJAX?

Comment: it's a function so /Controller/action

Comment: Can you also share the action code?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the property value, it will have the placeholder string for the macro in it. There is some code that runs as part of rendering the page that turns those into the actual Macros. I can't remember off the top of my head where that lives though.

Can you post the full code of the controller you are calling to update via AJAX? Is it a surface controller, an API controller, or something different?